# Apply different materials to same geo node setup

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Currently working on a small render, which has a very basic geo node setup to round fillets, so my knowledge is extremely limited on the geo node subject (to say the least).

I was wondering, what's the quickest way to **apply different materials to objects that have the same geo-node setup**? (Without having to duplicate the node setup and change the material in Set Material node)

[image]

Comment: as usual, as you would do it, if you are using the same material (which you do by "set material") - > you have to do it in the shader nodes.

Comment: ...or you make the material as input parameter in the group input node and change this in the modifier

Comment: Hey Chris , thanks for taking the time to reply, I'm using 2 different materials at the moment. How would the node setup for applying it to different objects look like in the shader nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this:

[image]

Just use material as input parameter for the group input node.

Comment: Holy cow! That worked faster than I thought, gonna save this GIF and make a note of it, thank you, thank you THANK YOU Chris!

Comment: glad i could help